# Batch Reverse Geocoding Not Working

Tags: arcgis-server, reverse-geocoding, geocoding-service

we have a (Geocode Service) which has enabled with Batch Geocoding parameters as

[image]

now when we test the service like

```
 {x:-83.000369, y:40.055185} , {x:-83.000031, y:40.051250}    ‍
```

‍
‍
at

[image]
It only returns one Point

```
Point:
X: -83.00030916909509
Y: 40.05520839180167
Spatial Reference: 4326  (4326)‍‍‍‍
```

‍‍‍‍can you please let me know what we are doing wrong?

Comment: As this is just a best guess - per the docs on [batch geocoding](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/geocode/api-reference/geocoding-geocode-addresses.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_351DE4FD98FE44958C8194EC5A7BEF7D), batch is specific to, well, batch geocoding. The batch setting you see is only for batch. There is no mention of the ability to 'batch' [reverse geocode](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/geocode/api-reference/geocoding-reverse-geocode.htm). In short my guess is reverseGeocode is XY at a time, operation.